# How to create cascading objects while offline with SmartStorage and the mobile SDK

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, smartstore, database.insert

Do you have any ideas how to create cascading objects (e.g. create a new `Soup A` entry that contains an also new `Soup B` relationship entry) while in offline modus and using the SmartStorage of the mobile SDK?

I need to related both objects the `Id` field value of the newly created `Soup B`entry, but without syncing it, the object does not have such a value.

Another idea was to use the `soupParentId` or `soupEntryId` but this also does not work and causes an expiation during a synchronize attempt.

Answer (score 0):

One method to achieve this would be to create internal unique Ids (in a new field on each object) and have that handle the pre-sync state, and then re-align base on IDs once they are available.

Note this is not a trivial thing in itself, and can even more complicated when records don't get inserted (or do and then are deleted for some reason). [MobileCaddy](http://www.mobilecaddy.net/) is a framework for building mobile/desktop apps for Salesforce that bakes all this in (and more), so as a dev you don't need to concern yourself with the details and failure scenarios, could be of use to you?